# Is this the correct way to use bridge table in a dimensional model?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a dimensional model using data from the following normalized data schema (see figure 1).  Notice that an **airman** can have multiple **certificate** records, and a **certificate** can have multiple **ratings**. While a certificate will only belong to one airman, ratings will be used to describe multiple certificates.

[image: Figure 1. Normalized version of the Data Model]

I need to be able to report on airmen by certificate type/level and by rating within a certificate.  To accomplish this goal I have created the following dimensional model (see figure 2) using bridge tables for the 1:n and n:n relationships ...

[image: Figure 2. Dimensional version of the Data Model]

Is this the correct way to model the data given how I will need to report on the data?

Comment: It sounds somewhat like the rating of certificates would be your fact (as that is the measurement that you're reporting on)? An airman would be a descriptive thing, and so a dimension rather than a fact. If you can figure out the key dimensions and measures/facts it will be easier to work out what should be a bridge.

Comment: @Rich I always assume that the thing you are wanting to count is the fact.  In my case, I am needing to count the number of airman by their certificate and rating.  Given this information, do you still think the rating would be the fact?

Comment: Yes, facts are usually 'business processes in which you take a measurement'. If it was customers who made sales, its still the sales that you're measuring (with customers being a dimension), even if later you might want to count distinct customers making a particular type of sale.